# unmerge netcdf ensemble from .nc4 file

Tags: netcdf, nco

I have a -nc4 that contains three .nc files. The files were merged with ncecat in the following way:

`ncecat --ovr -M -4 -u ensemble_member1.nc ensemble_member2.nc ensemble_member3.nc merged_ensemble.nc4`

I would like to *unmerge* the .nc4 file in the containing folder to recover the three .nc files. Is there a simple command for this?

Answer (score 1):

When `ncecat` merges ensembles with the command you show, it creates a record variable to glue them together as explained in the manual [here](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncecat). To disaggregate, hyperslab each ensemble out from the combined file and (optionally) average over the degenerate record dimension leftover from the glue, e.g.,

```
ncwa -a record -d record,0 in.nc ensemble1.nc
ncwa -a record -d record,1 in.nc ensemble2.nc
ncwa -a record -d record,2 in.nc ensemble3.nc
```